# Why would SetFile be unavailable after upgrading to Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, xcode, command-line

I have Xcode installed, and have used the SetFile command (installed with Xcode) for some time.  I just upgraded to Mountain Lion, though, and find that it is suddenly unavailable.  I verified that the upgrade did not wipe out Xcode—it's still there, and it runs fine—so I'm baffled as to why I suddenly cannot use SetFile.  All I can find by Googling points to installing Xcode (for people who don't have it).  What could be the problem for me?

Also, all my dot files seem to be unharmed, and my PATH looks normal, so I'm at a loss.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to install the command line tools from within Xcode.

Launch Xcode, go to `Preferences`, and from the `Downloads` tab, install the Command Line Tools if not installed yet.

[image]

Comment: Very strange that upgrading from Lion to Mt. Lion would remove the command line tools, but this solution worked!  Thanks!

Comment: @iconoclast, maybe you upgraded Xcode with the OS upgrade?

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it I think you're right.